# How to cancel/revoke a delayed task in another language other than Python?

Tags: python, go, celery, task-queue

We are using Celery as a task queue. It serves both our Django application and another app written in Go.

To create a task in celery in Go language, I can post a message directly into RabbitMQ with something like this:
https://github.com/bsphere/celery

But our Go app also needs to cancel a delayed task before it is executed. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe be use the method  [`.forget()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.forget) on a return from a task creation.